# Why is my mechanic occupied?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Every time I call my mechanic he says he's occupied. Anyone know why he is occupied?

Comment: Have you tried being on a main road (stand in the center of the road), and have your character look away from the road: look Straight up or straight down - then call him?

Comment: I already tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the answer.**
You need to pay your mechanic $50 daily. when you don´t have $50 at the point you need to pay him, you can´t use your mechanic for a week (ingame time). make sure you have $50 dollars at the end of the day.

Comment: This isn't right.  You pay him $50 *per day*, not per week.

Comment: It's not 50$ if you own a high-end apartment with a bigger garage, IIRC.

Comment: That will teach me... Not to run out of money 

Answer (score 9):

When you call a person or company that provides some service and they do not answer or are unable to help you, it means that whatever the service you are trying to get is **not possible** for one reason or another.

For example, when calling for a taxi and the operator tells you that there are no cabs in your area, it most likely means you are not near a road where a Taxi could realistically travel to.

The same goes for your mechanic - If you are on top of a mountain or in a submarine or parachuting or just out in the middle of nowhere, he can't bring the car to you, so he will say he is occupied. The other reason could be that you don't have enough money to pay him, so he is unwilling to deliver your car to you. A third option is that you don't have any cars - they have all been destroyed, sold, or impounded.

I haven't actually had all of these happen to me. The dialogue may be different based on the reason he can't help you. But if it's not clear, it should be one of those three reasons.

Comment: Has anyone tried calling the mechanic while you have wanted stars? That could be another reason. I'll test it when I can.

Comment: I have 2 cars and when I call my mechanic I'm always near a road. I called my mechanic 20 times but he's still ocupied.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have enough money to pay him the $50 per day (48 minutes real time)?

Comment: I't could be possible that I haven't paid him but that was a couple days ago. and yesterday it still worked.

Comment: I would make sure you have at least $50 and play for a while until you see the money come out of your balance. If it still doesn't work after that, then I'm stumped. Do you perhaps have a bounty? I haven't been lucky enough to receive one yet but maybe that's why your mechanic is afraid to help you.

Comment: I don't have a bounty. I'll just wait till he's not ocupied.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help! Looks like you're not the only one, and this may be a bug. If you haven't paid him once it's possible that he'll never help you again, even if you resume payments. [This person had to contact rockstar support to have it fixed](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200304667-Mechanic-Bug).

Comment: Emm, I once called him really close to my garage and he still didn't come.